# Sublevel sets with boundary of Lebesgue measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, convex-analysis

so I was wondering if the following is true: consider two smooth convex functions $f,g: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ and consider the sublevel sets
\begin{equation}
\{f\leq g\}.
\end{equation}
I don't mind assuming compactness, if that's neccesary. If $g$ is either constant or linear then these are convex sets, thus their boundary has Lebesgue measure zero. In general this is true for $g$ concaive, but is it true for smooth convex $g$? What if we also assume $g$ strongly convex? If not, could you provide a counterexample?

Comment: This is an interesting, rather tough question. Not at all clear what more context could be supplied!